# Обработка изображений

Tags: изображения, c++

На входе файл-изображение.
Необходимо получить попиксельную карту изображения (массив высота х ширина, в каждом - значения цветов по RGB). 
Каким образом это сделать максимально просто?
Особенно буду благодарен за кусок кода с хоть какими комментариями.
На край - подскажите простую библиотеку для этого, не хочется микроскопом орехи колоть.

Comment: А какие форматы изображений вас интересуют?

Comment: jpg/jpeg вполне подойдут, в худшем случае - переконвертировать их под заданый формат не будет такой сложной задачей

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Вот пример с использованием ImageMagick:

```
#include <Magick++.h>
#include <iostream>

int main() {
    Magick::InitializeMagick(0);
    Magick::Image image;
    image.read( "filename.{jpg,png,...}" );
    size_t width = image.baseColumns();
    size_t height = image.baseRows();
    std::cout << width << " x " << height << "\n";
    for (size_t row = 0; row < height; ++row)
        for (size_t col = 0; col < width; ++col) {
            Magick::ColorRGB c = image.pixelColor(row, col);
            // Здесь получаем тройки чисел от 0 до 1
            std::cout << "(" << c.red() << "," << c.green() << "," << c.blue() << ")";
        }
}
```